# Jquery Mobile AutoComplete POST Add Parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use Andy Matthews autocomplete for jquery mobile found [here](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js). My client service has a method that uses a parameter. I am not sure how to change my client side call to accept parameters?

Here is my client side call:

```
  //WHERE DO I PUT INPUT PARAMETERS??

   $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
                method: 'POST',
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: "ClientService.svc/REST/GetStates",
                link: 'target.html?term=',
                minLength: 1

            });
```

Here is my service:

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public List<string> GetStates(string y)
        {
            List<string> x= GetData(y);
            return x;

        }
```

Comment: Would you be willing to modify the plugin's source code? Do you have the uncompressed version of the plugin?

Comment: Yes that seems to what has to happen but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: And what you'd like to achieve is making `autocomplete` sending another parameter to the server, besides the term, isn't it?

Comment: If this is the case, is that parameter variable?

Comment: Right now the out of the box plugin will connect to my States method above with no parameters but I need to send a term in order for the autocomplete to be an autocomplete. I only need to send the term (string y) in my example method above

Comment: Sorry, I understand the JavaScript part, but not the service's one. What's the name of the param your service should receive? y? Excuse my ignorance :(

Comment: "y" is the "term" so I need to pass characters that the user types to the service so the service can filter and return the the autocomplete data

Comment: in a normal ajax call input parameters get passed through the "data" property. In this plugin they want you to pass on a querystring which wont work in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/jqm.autoComplete-1.4.3.js), it seems that the plugin doesn't allow passing custom `POST` parameters. What the user types in the box is sent in a parameter called `term`, but if you can't modify your service, what I would do is modifying the following part of the code:

```
...
} else {
$.ajax({
    type: settings.method,
    url: settings.source,
    // Change the following line
    // data: { term: text },
    // for:
    data: { y: text },
...
```

It's quite easy to find, as there's just one `$.ajax` call in the whole plugin.

Comment: How do I specify "text" in the autocomplete call above? I only have "method","target", "source"..etc

Comment: `text` would be what the user types in the box, if that is what you want to send, you wouldn't need to modify anything else

Comment: Changing the call from POST to GET had to be done too. POST does not work for some reason..Thanks for the help